How to convert a triangle into a vector triangle?
Clear["`*"]
labels = {Text[Style[A, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #1, {2, 0}], 
    Text[Style[B, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #2, {-2, 0}], 
    Text[Style[C, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #3, {2, -1}]} &;
triangles = {{{0, 0}, {8, 0}, {16, 75}}};
Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], Polygon[{##}], labels[##], 
    Arrow[{#1, #2}] & @@@ triangles, Arrow[{#2, #3}] & @@@ triangles, 
    Arrow[{#3, #1}] & @@@ triangles}, 
   ImageSize -> 80] & @@@ triangles

How to convert this triangle into a vector triangle, such as marking vector AB, vector CB, and vector CA?
The code above, after adding the 'Arrow' statement, did not draw the corresponding vector arrows.

What  is  vector  triangle?
Do  you  mean  change  {{ax, ay}, {bx, by}, {cx,     cy}}  to  {{{ax, ay}, {bx, by}}, {{bx, by}, {cx, cy}}, {{cx,      cy}, {ax, zy}}}?

@cvgmt Label each side of the triangle with an arrow to indicate that it is a directed line segment representing a vector.


Maybe Partition[#, 2, 1, 1].

Clear[triangles]
labels = {Text[Style[A, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #1, {2, 0}], 
    Text[Style[B, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #2, {-2, 0}], 
    Text[Style[C, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #3, {2, -1}]} &;
triangles = {{{0, 0}, {8, 0}, {16, 75}}, {{1, 1}, {4, 2}, {9, 8}}};
Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], Arrowheads[Medium], Polygon@#,
     Arrow@Partition[#, 2, 1, 1], labels @@ #}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 1.2] & /@ triangles



$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

labels = {Text[Style[A, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #[[1]], {2, 0}],
    Text[Style[B, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #[[2]], {-2, 0}],
    Text[Style[C, FontFamily -> "Times", 15], #[[3]], {2, -1}]} &;
vertices = {{0, 0}, {8, 0}, {16, 75}};
Graphics[{
    labels[##],
    Arrowheads[{-.1, .1}],
    Arrow[{#[[1]], #[[2]]}],
    Arrow[{#[[2]], #[[3]]}],
    Arrow[{#[[3]], #[[1]]}]},
   ImageSize -> 80] &@vertices


